# How do I allow a user to pick a background colour of my website with a colour chooser and store it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```html
<input name="Color Picker" id="picker" onclick="setColor()" type="color" />
```

```js
function setColor() {
  getColor();
  if (localStorage.getItem('background') !== null) {
    getColour = localStorage.background;
    $('body').css('background', getColour);
  }
}

function getColor() {
  localStorage.getItem('background') = picker;

}
```

I want to take the user input for the custom colour and update the website background accordingly.

Comment: there is a lot of color picker plugin out there. try to get 1 and try it out

Answer (score 1):

Stackoverflow snippets doesn't seem to like using `localStorage` so here is an example how to read and write colors. I commented out the local storage code for you to use in your application instead of the temp variable I used toi demonstrate the code.

Example below uses the `onchange` and stores the current color on load, has a default color you can apply clicking a button and has another button to apply the store/selected color.

```js
var defaultColor = '#00ff00';
var tempStorage;

function setColor() {
  //localStorage.setItem('background', $('#picker').val());
  tempStorage = $('#picker').val();
  $('body').css('background-color', tempStorage);
  applyBackgroundColor(tempStorage);
}

function getColor() {
  //localStorage.getItem('background');
  $('#picker').val(tempStorage);
  applyBackgroundColor(tempStorage);
}

function getDefaultColor() {
  $('#picker').val(defaultColor);
  applyBackgroundColor(defaultColor);
}

function applyBackgroundColor(colorValue){
  $('body').css('background-color', colorValue);
}

setColor();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="Color Picker" id="picker" onchange="setColor()" type="color" />
<button onclick="getDefaultColor()">Apply Default</button>
<button onclick="getColor()">Apply Stored</button>
```

> Please note I used your own syntax and tried changing as little as
>   possible to your original code, i.e: How you call the methods inline,
>   etc..
>
> Though in general I would recommend to not use inline bindings but use
>   jQuery `$(element).on('event', function(){})` instead. i.e:
>   `$(#picker).on('change', setColor)`

Comment: Also, the button for the default value does not work

Comment: works in the snippet... not sure what you mean by it doesn't work.

Comment: I mean it does not work for saving the value when the page is refreshed

Comment: I hope you are not just copying the answer into your application hoping it will work as there is parts in it purely to demonstrate the code. I'm also calling `setColor()` during page load to make this demo work which is **not** something you want to do in your actual application! Though you might want to call `getColor()` on load. The default button is only for this specific example to show how to apply the color to a picker. The set and get methods have the local storage code commented out included you can copy that code from the example into your application and update as needed.

Comment: The demo contains all relevant information, how you implement the relevant parts into your application is up to you.

Comment: Francine! How would I store the value in local storage for a user without the color picker resetting to black????????????????????????????

Comment: @R31D - Just Fran is fine, I'm a dude. I'm not sure I understand what you are asking but all the code is there in the example/demo above. Use the code and apply it how you need it in your application. If you want your color picker to be set to the value from loclaStorage then do that. I included how to read values from localStorage in commented lines above, use them when needed and set the color picker to that value `$('#picker').val(<localStorage Value in Here>);`

Comment: Francis or Franklin?

Comment: Name is Account Name **Fran**

Answer (score 0):

Change your methods to (*comments inline*)

```
<input name="Color Picker" id="picker" type="color"/>

document.querySelector( "input[type='color']" ).addEventListener( "click", function(){
      setColor(this);        
});
function setColor( ele ){
    getColor();
    if( localStorage.getItem('background') ) { //notice that empty value is also checked
        $('body').css('background-color', ele.value ); //value directly picked from ele
    }
}
function getColor( ele ){
    localStorage.setItem('background', ele.value ); //notice that ele's value is picked up
}
```

And this can be further compressed to

```
document.querySelector( "input[type='color']" ).addEventListener( "click", function(){
    if( this.value  ) { //notice that empty value is also checked
        $('body').css('background-color', this.value ); 
        localStorage.setItem('background', this.value ); 
    }
});
```

Comment: what is meant by 'ele' as a condition for the functions?

Comment: `ele` is the element which is clicked. Notice that i passed `this` while calling `setColor(this)`.

Comment: I have, no success sadly. Should i remove the background colour from CSS? would this affect it?

Comment: Can you share your attempt? Try with background-color